# Rails Paperclip image compression compared to what Page Speed produces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compression, paperclip, deflate

I've set up paperclip in rails and everything is working hunky-dory (i actually had to google that...:).

I've noticed however that Page Speed tells me I could losslessly compress my thumbnail and large images (the ones that paperclip produces) further.  Is there an option I can put into my model which does this?  I've noticed that mod_deflate doesn't compress images (I'm using Firefox).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add compression to paperclip processing using the [paperclip-compression gem](https://github.com/dakick/paperclip-compression).

In your Gemfile:

```
gem "paperclip-compression", "~> 0.1.1"
```

(of course run bundle install)

In your model:

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
                :styles     => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
                :processors => [:thumbnail, :compression]
```

"*jpegtran* works by rearranging the compressed data (DCT coefficients), without ever fully decoding the image. Therefore, [its transformations are lossless](http://linux.die.net/man/1/jpegtran)"

Note: if you are running on heroku, you'll need jpegtran, and optipng binaries added to your application.  Here's a good article on [running binaries on heroku](http://bindle.me/blog/index.php/405/running-binaries-on-heroku).

Comment: Would this work with Rails 2.3? The application is failing to start.

Comment: Not sure if this would work in 2.3.  I'm using it in 3.2.  Check the paperclip-compression dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You should do your own testing on various JPEG compression levels but I've noticed that I can bump ImageMagicks quality setting down to 75 and still not see any noticeable difference - with about a 30-40% file size savings.

My model looks like:

```
  has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles => {
      :"185x138" => {
        :geometry => "185x138>"
      }    },
    :convert_options => {
      :all => "-auto-orient",
      :"185x138" => "-quality 75",
```

`-quality 75` is for ImageMagick. If you're using a different processor you will need to adjust accordingly.

Comment: I'm still seeing that "I could get a 22% reduction in size by losslessly compressing the image" according to Page Speed.

Answer (score 0):

What about FFMPEG or AVCONV?

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg/avconv
```

= initializer

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/" # see `which ffmpeg`
```

= Modal

```
after_save :compress_with_ffmpeg

def compress_with_ffmpeg
  [:thumb, :original, :medium].each do |type|
    img_path = self.avtar.path(type)
    Paperclip.run("ffmpeg", " -i #{img_path} #{img_path}")
  end
end
```